# Use existing private account as a user member in corporate account

Tags: docusignapi

Imagine that user Foo Bar has personal DocuSign account **Foo Bar [foo.bar.com]**.
This user is working for organization that has a corporate DocuSign account and this organization needs to add Foo Bar  as a user member inside corporate account (mostly to be able to send envelopes as [SendOnBehalfOf](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm) this user).

I tried to use [REST API: Add User](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References%2FAdd%20User%20to%20Account.htm) but I get Bad Request

```
 [
    {
      "email": "foo@bar.com",
      "userName": "Foo Bar",
      "errorDetails": {
        "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
        "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
      }
    }
  ]
```

Which is expected. But is it possible to accomplish this goal one way or another (Using DocuSign API)?

Comment: Which credentials are you using in X-DocuSign-Authentication?  That should have the credentials for an existing administrator user on the account (because they have permission to add users).

Comment: Ditto what Jeff has said, check the username + pwd combo for the credentials you are passing in the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add user membership for username+password combination that corresponds to existing DocuSign accound you just need to send 'Create User' request without password.

```
var error = apiClient.CreateUser(name, mail, pass);
if (error == "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED")
{
    error = apiClient.CreateUser(name, mail, NULL);
    if (error != null)
    {
        Fail!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add existing users to your corporate DocuSign account, you just need to make sure:

1. You reference their information correctly (must specify the same exact `email` + `username` combination).
2. You are an account admin in the account you are trying to add the user to.

If you're an admin and you specify the correct information you'll be able to add them to the account.